# I cant click on a dropdown element using selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, dropdown

I want to click on "Mon profil" 
I tried :

```
driver.findElement(By.className("profile-navbar-label dropdown-item")).click()
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'" + "Mon profil" + "')]")).click()
```

**it doesnt work**

[image]

Comment: Please do not include code as screenshots. You can copy and paste the code in to your question from the browser debug console. Reading code in screenshots is too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Xpath`.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Mon profil')]")).click()
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Mon profil']")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use class name with space to find element. If you wanna use such class name you have write xpath for that.So first way of finding is wrong and about `xpath` I am not sure if that is a correct way to write down xpath.

Try this xpath= `(.//button[@type='button'])[1]` it will work.

You can check the `xpath` is locating the correct web element by clicking on F12 and then `ctrl+F`. Enter `xpath` it will highlight the webelement.

Answer (score 0):

First you should click on the select box, when the drop down is displayed , use the following code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Mon profil']")).click()
```

OR

```
WebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Mon profil']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
```